# Running jQuery's $(document).ready(function() {...}); inside an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an application that builds page content from multiple page fragments comprising the template page. One or more of these fragments need to run JavaScript when the document has loaded, and it does not make sense to put fragment specific code in the template page comprising the fragments. While this approach has worked out for me quite well, I have a problem when attempting to update a fragment via Ajax based on the user's interaction with the page.

I am using jQuery and `$(document).ready(function() {...});` rather liberally, both in the template page (for globally scoped code) and the fragments (for fragment specific code). Problem is, when a fragment is updated using jQuery's `.html(HTML code from Ajax response)` on the jQuery enriched version of the HTML element and the Ajax response itself contains `$(document).ready(function() {...});` code, the HTML content gets updated nicely but the JS does not execute.

Some suggest use of `eval()` on the JS fragments inside the Ajax response while others forbid it. I am hoping someone will push me in the right direction with this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(formObj).attr('action'),
    data: $(formObj).serialize(),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $response = $(data.replace(/<body(.*?)>/,'<body$1><div id="ajaxResBody">').replace('</body>','</div></body>'));
    $('#fragmentContent').html($response.find('#fragmentContent').html());
});
```

`<div id="fragmentContent">...</div>` is one of the fragments updated using partial content extracted from the Ajax response. When the page is initially loaded, the fragment's content DOM looks approximately like this:

```
<div id="fragmentContent">
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // JS code
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

But when the same fragment's content is replaced via Ajax, the DOM looks like this:

```
<div id="fragmentContent">
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

So it is quite apparent scripts are stripped. I verified that by using the following code:

```
if (data.indexOf('accordion(') >= 0) {
    console.log('scripts found in Ajax response');
    if ($response.find('#fragmentContent').html().indexOf('accordion(') >= 0) {
        console.log('scripts inserted into fragment');
    }
    else {
        console.log('scripts stripped before content inserted into fragment!');
    }
}
else {
    console.log('scripts did not even make it in the Ajax response!');
}
```

and the following log output was yielded:

```
scripts found in Ajax response
scripts stripped before content inserted into fragment!
```

Comment: i seriously doubt document ready has anything to do with your problem. You are also probably overusing it. If the document is already ready, the callback will be executed immediately, meaning it should *work* regardless of where you place it, as long as jquery exists.

Comment: @KevinB all instances document ready works just fine when the whole page loads initially. It is only upon subsequently updates to the page (via Ajax), when the fragment HTML is individually retrieved and inserted into the page, that the embedded document ready code (within the fragment) does not execute.

Comment: Have you placed console.logs inside it to see that it doesn't execute? are you sure it isn't just not finding the elements due to executing too early?

Comment: @KevinB yes I did add console.log calls inside the fragment's JS. Those log statements are seen only in the initial page load, but not when content is retrieved via Ajax.

Comment: That means your javascript is being stripped from the content some how. Can you show an example of loading in additional html that contains a script and adding it to the DOM? might also help to see the html+script that's being appended.

Comment: @KevinB see the updates to my original post... I added some code and HTML that hopefully addresses your question(s).

Comment: You want to look the duplicate question with answers [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246299/does-ajax-loaded-content-get-a-document-ready).