# Function to determine if DOM and Images are loaded within AJAX call .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an function to dynamically load content via Ajax using this way:

```
$("#content").load('file.html', function(response, status, xhr){
     alert('test');
});
```

The alert loads when the request is succesfull but before any images are loaded. Is there any function I can use that triggers after all images (within file.html) are loaded and the DOM is fully ready? I've tried the usual, like $(window).load and $(document).ready, but that obviously would not work, which makes sense.

**Edit for future reference:**
To clarify, I was using skrollr on the content loaded. Since that plugin adapts the body height based on the content loaded, it messed up badly on ios devices. Using this function I can make sure the skrollr instance is not refreshed too early.

Comment: you should use `$.get()` instead and set some logic inside success callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`imagesloaded`**](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) jQUery plugin, try to use inside ajax `done` callback function on loaded content, see below sample code

```
$("#content").load('file.html', function(response, status, xhr){
     $("#content").imagesLoaded( function(){
          alert('test');
     });

});
```

Comment: but `load()` complete callback is fired ***after*** response added to the DOM: `If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.`

Comment: yes, `OP` want to trigger when ajax content all images loaded this plugin provide solution, and he can hide content while images not loaded

Comment: i guess OP wants to append it to the DOM only once all images loaded. Following your edit, ya it could be a solution

Comment: it's not possible, but he can apply trick, that would be work same as `OP` want to do

Comment: This trick works perfectly. To clarify, I was using skrollr on the content loaded. Since that plugin adapts the body height based on the content loaded, it messed up badly on ios devices. Using this function I can make sure the skrollr instance is not refreshed too early.

Comment: @sv88 gland to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is answered by this post, [Does AJAX loaded content get a "document.ready"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246299/does-ajax-loaded-content-get-a-document-ready). Short answer is no, it isn't, and you need to add a listener for the items inside the loaded content. That should be easy though.