# JQuery ClueTip with ColdFusion - Javascript $(document).ready() misfire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion, cluetip

I was wondering if `$(document).ready(...)` fires for a cluetip content page, in general, after it is loaded. It doesn't seem to at all if the content page is a .cfm, however I have yet to try this for a normal .htm file (I'm assuming there is no difference since after the CF server processes the CF markup, the remaining page handling/loading behavior should be standard (I'd like to image so anyway).

If anyone requires/prefers a code example please let me know, I just don't have the nerve right at this moment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ColdFusion generates HTML. The browser sees the same thing either way.

Comment: I realize that aside from the .cfm extension, pure html is returned. The unknown here is how cluetip handles the loaded content page. It seems to prevent $(document).ready() from firing.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding document.ready [Does AJAX loaded content get a “document.ready”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246299/does-ajax-loaded-content-get-a-document-ready). Not sure exactly which clueTip plugin you are using, but it sounds like you are looking for some sort of callback or `load` event, rather than document.ready()

Comment: @Leigh Thanks Leigh. Throw that comment into an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Leigh Your absolutely right, and I commend your nobility :)