# reRender and window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, onload, rerender

Is it possible to use element onload after a reRendering of a div?

My div: populatedChart is reRendered after a button click and is populated with data. Once the div is loaded with the data, I want to check for specific information and act upon that information. My thought was to do this with an **onload** function. But it is not working as I expected. So I am not sure if it is even possible. Does anyone know?

```
   <div class="tableOP" id="populatedChart" onload="populatedChartOnload">
      <div class="rowOP headerOP greenOP">
         <div class="cell cheaderOP panel-heading green-panel">
         This is your Report
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rowOP oddOP">
         <div class="cellOP companyname paddingStyleCompName" id="blankComp">
         {!bvs.Status__c}
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>

function populatedChartOnload(){                                
    if ('{!bvs.Status__c}' != 'Completed') { 
    document.getElementById("populatedChart").style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use `onload="populatedChartOnload();"`

Comment: I asked this question some time ago, It may also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314240/recall-window-load-event-javascript

Comment: @Feathercrown, good catch but still does not work.

Comment: @Zze, thank you for the reference, it looks like you did deal with something similar. I am going to try the .load that was suggested on your thread. I will update if I get the answer!

Comment: @Olivia Goodluck! Let me know how it goes.