# Javascript scroll pagination is retrieving the same data from databese

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using javascript scroll pagination in my website. When a page is srcolled down, some items are loaded from database. The issue is that, sometime, scroll pagination is getting  the same data from database. I have used `async: false`. But, it slowed the loading down.
Javascript code:

```
if (check !== null) {
  $(window).scroll(function(ev) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight >= $('#footer').offset().top) {
      var last_id = $(".item:last").data("id");

      loadData(last_id);
    };

  });
}

var dataCount = 1;

function loadData(last_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'some/url/loader',
    type: "get",
    data: {
      id: last_id
    },
    // async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        dataCount++;
        $('#div').append(data);
        check = 1;
      } else if (!data) {
        console.warn('no data');
        check = null;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Loader method in a controller:

```
public function actionLoader() {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
  $posts = SomeModel::getItems($id);

  if (!empty($posts)) {
    $q = $this - > renderPartial('view', array('data' => $posts));
    echo $q;
  }
}
```

Comment: Most probably `last_id = $(".item:last").data("id")` refers to the same ID. Try keeping track of what was already fetched with an arr and add another check to make sure JS doesn't fetched an already fetched ID

Comment: ajax loaded content isn't in the DOM and so last id will be the last of the one that didnt load via ajax, hence you getting the same results

Comment: @delboy1978uk why ajax loaded content isn't in the DOM? he appends content to the DOM: `$('#div').append(data)`

Comment: yes that's true, but because it wasn't there originally, you need to add fresh listeners, possibly by calling a function in the success method

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246299/does-ajax-loaded-content-get-a-document-ready#20246940

Comment: But there is `$(window).scroll()` event, not on dynamicaly added element...